# Finding current page number in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added the following custom loop in my Wordpress template:

```
$args = array(
    'category__not_in' => array($featured_cat->term_id),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in' => array($recent_post)
);
query_posts($args);
```

For pagination to work, I guess I need to pass another arg `paged` with the current page number. What is the way to get the current page number in Wordpress?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Not near a wordpress system to test this out at the mo, but you should be able to use:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

(obviously defaulting to 1, if it has not been sent through).

Comment: you actually don't need to default to 1. the default is 0, and if you pass `paged=0` to query_posts, it acts the same as `paged=1`. (at least, this is true in wordpress 3.0)

Comment: You don't even need to use the comparison. Since WP 3.9.0, `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', $default )` allows a second argument with the default value. So, `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 )` or `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 0 )` (as @Kip noticed) will do.

Answer (score 18):

using variable $paged.

```
global $paged;
echo $paged;
```

Comment: Just be aware with this, that it will be 0 on page 1.

Answer (score 6):

For 'Page x of y' I use this:

```
<?php 

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
echo $paged.' of '.$wp_query->max_num_pages; 

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<?php echo '(Page '.$page.' of '.$wp_query->max_num_pages.')'; ?>
```

Comment: `$page` always return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_query_var('paged')` like this

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array('category__not_in' => array($featured_cat->term_id), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => array($recent_post), 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts($args); 
?>
```